using windows vnc client to connect to wayvnc on raspberry pi
I recently got a new Raspberry Pi 5 and enabled VNC on it. Apparently, by default, the Raspberry Pi 5 OS uses wayvnc as a VNC server.
I then tried to connect to that Raspberry Pi with UltraVNC 1.4.3.6 and that gave me a "No supported authentication methods!" error
I tried TightVNC 2.8.81 and got this error instead:

Error in TightVNC Viewer: No security types supported. Server sent security types, but we do not support any of them.

So how do I view the security types and change them?
FWIW my /etc/wayvnc/config file has this in it:
use_relative_paths=true
address=::
enable_auth=true
enable_pam=true
private_key_file=tls_key.pem
certificate_file=tls_cert.pem
rsa_private_key_file=rsa_key.pem

Any ideas?
